# Watir Gem Locate Legend role="button"

Tags: hyperlink, legend, watir

I can't seem to get `Watir` to locate a `link` on a page, which reveals another two `fields`.  But, the link isn't a link, but a `li` that is a `legend`:

```
<li> 
  <legend role="button" tabindex="1" id="alpha-trigger" class="trigger legend shown " aria-label="alpha Search"" for="alpha">
    Alpha Search
  </legend>
</li>
```

I've tried using `.exists?` and looking for that `dom object`, but I've always come up empty.  I see that it isn't a timing issue, as I'm not using `headless` for `chrome`.

Can anybody recommend how I can see this link to `.click` it?  Cheers

Comment: What did you try and what errors did you get? My initial guess would be to try `browser.legend(id: 'alpha-trigger').click`.

Comment: @JustinKo Tried various types, one of them was just that.  The errors that I get are either timeout because not found, or not found (`.exist?`).

Comment: .exists method won't wait. It checks and immediately returns you true or false. It won't wait for element to appear.

Comment: I had `.wait_until(&:present?).exists?` and various other trials.  I always get `false` or `timeout` on this.  The `identifier` is off and I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Use this code and try. `b.element(xpath: "//legend[text()='Alpha Search']").click`

Comment: @Rajagopalan Didn't work.  Is that `waitir` or `watir-nokogiri`?  Can I use `xpath` for an `.exists?`?

Comment: Is it in a frame or iframe?

Comment: @JustinKo Looking at its parent, I get this: `#<Watir::Div: located: false; {:class=>"field-section", :tag_name=>"div"}>`  [link](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/location/23?region=NewYork)  Choose "birth/marriage/residence/death..." as those are the links I need.

Comment: `element` recognition apparently ends at `<fs-search-form>`.  `<form id="form">` is not viewable by Watir.

Comment: Ah, the link to the page helps a lot. The element is in a shadow DOM, which Watir doesn't have a lot of support for. There was a previous question/answer about interacting with the shadow DOM that you could try - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541701/1200545

Comment: OK trying to push this out.   I'm not even sure what the shadowRoot is.  I'm assuming it's `a.element(css: "fs-search-form")` (a is my browser).  Tested, that form exists.  `#shadow-root (open)` appears right underneath it, but it appears yet again below that.  Error: `javascript error: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: @Justin Ko I used your solution and met the same problem that he is saying. And created a question two days ago. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768912/javascript-error-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined

Comment: Looks like Selenium and/or Webdriver has made substantial changes, so I'll have to take a look what the options are now.

Comment: Might be promising.  Looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the element is in a shadow DOM, which does not yet have support in Selenium/Watir. At this point, the fastest solution seems to be executing everything by JavaScript.

For example, clicking the Marriage link:

```
browser.execute_script('return document
  .querySelector("fs-search-form")
  .shadowRoot
  .querySelector("[group-id=event]")
  .shadowRoot
  .querySelector("#marriage-trigger")
  .click();')
```

Note that you need to explicitly navigate to the element containing the shadow DOM and call `shadowRoot` to go inside.

Comment: OK, that did the selection, however the new revealed fields are not selectable.  `browser.element(id: "marriage-trigger").exists? ==> false`.

Comment: This solution doesn't change whether the elements can be interacted with by Watir. Any element in the shadow DOM (ie including the element with id "marriage-trigger") will need to be interacted with using JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately. I'll keep poking around for a better solution, but at least this will give you an option to keep proceeding.